# Daylight Saving Time - Java

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I have the following timezone **"2021-06-06T06:00+01:00[Europe/London]"**

When I call `toInstant()` on that timezone, I get "2021-06-06T05:00". Clocks go forward, so why is it returning 5 am? I am trying to get 7 am rather than 5 am.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
    ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.of(
            2021, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
    System.out.println(zoned);
    System.out.println(zoned.toInstant());
```

Expected output: 2021-06-06T07:00

Observed output:

> ```
> 2021-06-06T06:00+01:00[Europe/London]
> 2021-06-06T05:00:00Z
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code 1**

```
ZoneId tzLondon = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, tzLondon);
Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
System.out.println("  zoned: " + zonedDateTime);
System.out.println("instant: " + instant);
```

**Output 1**

```
  zoned: 2021-06-06T06:00+01:00[Europe/London]
instant: 2021-06-06T05:00:00Z
```

The zoned output is based on the timezone Europe/London, which is [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)+1 during Daylight Saving Time (DST), which is why it seems to be 1 hour after the instant output (05:00 + 1 hour = 06:00). But both outputs represent the same point in time, just in different formats.

Usually in Java, you don't deal with DST calculation directly, because Java does it for you. You can see this, when you take the ZonedDateTime from above, and add a few months.

**Code 2**

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeAFewMonthsLater = zonedDateTime.plusMonths(5);
Instant instantAFewMonthsLater = zonedDateTimeAFewMonthsLater.toInstant();
System.out.println("A few months later   (zoned): " + zonedDateTimeAFewMonthsLater);
System.out.println("A few months later (instant): " + instantAFewMonthsLater);
```

**Output 2**

```
A few months later   (zoned): 2021-11-06T06:00Z[Europe/London]
A few months later (instant): 2021-11-06T06:00:00Z
```

But if you really really want to patch your `ZonedDateTime` from 06:00 to 07:00, depending on its DST properties, you can do this. But it's dirty.

**Code 3**

```
Duration dstDuration = zonedDateTime.getZone().getRules().getDaylightSavings(instant);
ZonedDateTime dstPatchedZonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.plus(dstDuration);
System.out.println("DST patched: " + dstPatchedZonedDateTime);
```

**Output 3**

```
DST patched: 2021-06-06T07:00+01:00[Europe/London]
```

Comment: @OleV.V. right, `java.time` is the modern way, and date/time classes from `java.util` are to avoid. I adjusted my answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

## 2021-06-06T06:00+01:00 = 
2021-06-06T05:00+00:00

This is simply how timezone offsets are defined, check for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

A timezone designator of `+01:00` means the given time is in a timezone 1 hour ahead of UTC, meaning the same time in UTC is the given time minus 1 hour.

Therefore `2021-06-06T06:00+01:00` is the same moment as `2021-06-06T05:00+00:00`, without daylight saving time it would be 1 hour earlier in the day.

```
ZonedDateTime
.parse( "2021-06-06T06:00+01:00[Europe/London]" )
.toInstant()
.toString()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/3MUZcS).

> 2021-06-06T05:00:00Z